# Personalizar reporte de excel generado con html y jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, excel

Estoy tratando de exportar una tabla común de html a excel usando Jquery.
Mi script ya imprime la tabla, lo que necesito es personalizar los nombres que aparecen en los headers  asi como tamaños de las columnas, colores etc.

Esta es la imagen de mi reporte, se puede ver como los headers es un completo desorden.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe algun ejemplo que me puedan proporcionar, Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Nos puedes mostrar el código de que como estás haciendo la exportación?

Comment: Este es un script que encontre en internet   http://prnt.sc/ctic6h

Comment: Por favor, añade el código a la pregunta y no sólo capturas de pantalla o enlaces a sitios externos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo utilizo Dompdf para generar mis excel,debes descargar la libreria en el siguiente enlace [Pulsar](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) y esta es la manera de generar los excel con datos de tu PHP. El diseño, colores ancho de las columnas las generas apartir de tu HTML.

```
    <?php
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=tuexcel.xls");
    include("../php/conexion.php");
    $post=$_POST["post"];
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>STu Titulo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <p style="margin:0px;font-size:20px" align="center"><b>Titulo<b></p>
    <p align="center" style="margin:0px;font-size:16px" ><i>SubTitulo</i></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
    <td><p style="margin:0px;font-size:12px" > direccion</p></td>
    <td><p style="margin:0px;font-size:12px" > Telefono </p></td>
    <td><p style="margin:0px;font-size:12px" > Ciudad </p></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
      <tr style="font-size: 12px;" align="center" >
    <td align="right">Semestre    :</td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $semestry; ?></td>
    <td align="right">Unidad de Aprendizaje    :</td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $ua; ?> </td>
    </tr>
        <tr style="font-size: 12px;" align="center" >
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td align="right">Algo:</td>
            <td align="left"><?php echo $ut;?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Si la respuesta te ha sido util no olvides votar.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, estoy probando saludos

Comment: Si te ha sido util favor de votar

Comment: Estoy trabajando en un sistema un poco viejo el cual utiliza **php: 
5.2.17 ** y estoy leyendo que DomPdf utiliza **Php 5.3**.  sabes que versión de Dompdf puede trabajar con esta versión de PHP?? @Rastalovely

Comment: No amigo, creo que seria mas sencillo si actualizas la version de tu PHP y Mysql, No olvides que en el área de las Tics debemos estar actualizados de manera constante. Solo actualiza la versión de tu Xampp o WampServer

Comment: Si amigo entiendo, solo que este proyecto me lo asignaron para hacer estas actualizaciones, actualizar la versión de Xampp me traería problemas es por eso que decidí utilizar solo *jquery*.. Alguna sugerencia como se puede modificar este reporte?? saludos.. @Rastalovely